# Soap XML and PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

Completely new with soap. 
I have this WSDL link. 
http://mylink.com/somehint.asmx?WSDL

The method name is "Price".

I have to set up a request like this.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:Price>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:request>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:Username>MyUsername</tem:Username>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:Password>Mypassword</tem:Password>
            <tem:Customer>002399</tem:Customer>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:FromRes>23245</tem:FromRes>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:ToRes>12334</tem:ToRes>
            <tem:Weight>39</tem:Weight>

         </tem:request>
      </tem:Price>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But how do I write this in php?

So far I've written this, but that does not work. I'm not surprised if everything is wrong.

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://mylink.com/somehint.asmx?WSDL', array('trace' => 1));
$res = $client->SoapFunction(array('Username'=>'Myusername','password'=>'Mypassword','Customer'=>'002399'));
```

Comment: add trace option  as true and view your request is correctly generated.

Comment: @Amila thanks for answering, I've tried that and I still get nothing. I've also checked with __getFunctions() that the method exists.

Comment: If you have issue , first better to try with SoapUI to check is it working correctly.

Comment: @Amila I've checked it there, and it's working perfectly in soapUI.

Comment: print __getLastRequest() and see the soap request pass correctly.

Comment: @Amila Thank also gives me nothing. Nothing is printed at all.

Comment: Try this to see the request. 

 echo $client->__getLastRequest();

Answer (score 0):

i use something like that in my code perhaps that can help you to solve your issue ! I tried to adapt it from you data but perhaps you need to tweak it a little ^^

```
$params = array('request'=>
                        array(
                              'Username' => 'Myusername',
                              'Password' => 'Mypassword',
                              'Customer' => 'Mycustomer',
                              'FromRes'  => 'Mypfromres',
                              'ToRes'    => 'Myptores',
                              'Weight'   => 'Mypweight'
                        ));

$wsdl = 'http://mylink.com/somehint.asmx?wsdl';

$options = array(
                 'uri'                => 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
                 'style'              => SOAP_RPC,
                 'use'                => SOAP_ENCODED,
                 'soap_version'       => SOAP_1_1,
                 'cache_wsdl'         => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
                 'connection_timeout' => 15,
                 'trace'              => true,
                 'encoding'           => 'UTF-8',
                 'exceptions'         => true,
                 );

try {
    $soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
    $data = $soap->Price($params);
}

catch(Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

print_r($data);
```

Regards.